# Issue in installing clang

Tags: clang, llvm

I'm trying to install clang and llvm as mentioned in this link 
http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html. However I require llvm-config in one of my code. I cannot find llvm-config in /usr/bin directory which has other llvm commands. Does this mean llvm/clang installation is corrupted?
Thanks

Comment: Is it in your build directory?  That is, did it not get built, or just not installed?

Comment: yes it is there in ../llvm/Release/bin directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_31/ llvm31
cd llvm31
cd tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/branches/release_31/ clang
cd ..
./configure --enable-optimized --disable-doxygen --prefix=~/llvm31
make 
make install
```

Comment: I  have no root/sudo access, hence can't make install.

Comment: change the prefix to something you can reach  ~/llvm31, or whatever

Comment: +1 @dwelch.  suzanne, why are you surprised there's no `llvm-config` in `/usr/bin` if you can't put it there?